# Dirstack: index starts with 0

Tags: linux, command-line, zsh, cd-command

Zsh: 5.6.2

I use dirstack from archwiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh#Dirstack

All `setopt`s in script are on, script is sourced in `~/.zshrc`,

It works before and somehow change index to `0`, afaik zsh's array should start from 1.

current unexpected output with `0`:

```
dirs -v
0       ~/.cache/downloads/documents
1       ~
2       ~/.cache/zsh
3       ~/.zsh/scripts
```

try to cd

```
cd -<tab>
0 -- ~/.zsh/scripts
1 -- ~/.cache/zsh
2 -- ~
```

If I choose 1 then it cd to ~/.zsh/scripts instead of ~/.cache/zsh

Answer (score 1):

What goes after `~` is not an index in a zsh array variable. See

```
info zsh 'Filename Expansion'
```

> A '~' by itself is replaced by the value of $HOME.  A '~' followed by a
>   '+' or a '-' is replaced by current or previous working directory,
>   respectively.
>
> A '~' followed by a number is replaced by the directory at that position
>   in the directory stack.  '~0' is equivalent to '~+', and '~1' is the top
>   of the stack.  '~+' followed by a number is replaced by the directory at
>   that position in the directory stack.  '~+0' is equivalent to '~+', and
>   '~+1' is the top of the stack.  '~-' followed by a number is replaced by
>   the directory that many positions from the bottom of the stack.  '~-0'
>   is the bottom of the stack.  The PUSHD_MINUS option exchanges the
>   effects of '~+' and '~-' where they are followed by a number.

Though in effect, unless you enable the `ksh_arrays` or `pushd_minus` option, `~1` does happen to expand to the same thing as `$dirstack[1]` while `~0` expands to the same thing as `$PWD`, `~-0` to the same thing as `$dirstack[-1]`, `~-1` to the same thing as `$dirstack[-2]`.

Comment: I have option `pushd_minus` `on` but it still showing from 0, btw I had multiple zsh session (probably I'm using tmux). I end with writing fuzzy list to choose recent dirs instead. Thanks.